# "Shelf"-life of frozen Kaffir lime leaves

Tags: freezing, storage-lifetime, herbs

A scale infection ruined my vision of a constant supply of fresh Kaffir lime leaves. I salvaged the unaffected leaves and now have a baggie full of frozen leaves in my freezer - My local asian food store sells them frozen and I figured I'd take a leaf out of their book.

**But how long will they stay fresh?**

Of course I could buy a large bag of rice and a crate of coconut milk and put Thai/Vietnamese/... on the menu five days a week, but to prevent domestic mutiny I'd like to stretch that bag of leaves way longer.

I checked our [canonical post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) and the links given there, but couldn't find a conclusive answer. And of course I'm wondering about quality, not food safety.

Comment: Is it a frost free freezer?

Comment: Your only risk is freezer burn....I would vacuum pack.  I'll bet you could get 6 months easy...if not longer.

Comment: The ones sold in plastic tubs by asian grocers usually last a year or more (some will develop freezer burn around the edges... so what, you use the ones that are unaffected) ... we cannot know HOW they were frozen, though (might have been flash frozen or pre-cooled in a blast chiller). BTW, Thai/Vietnamese 5 days a week sounds like a great way to PREVENT domestic mutiny to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering from personal experience: 
Mine are in the freezer now for 5+ months, and don't show any sign of degradation. Not in smell, not in texture, not in color, not in taste. I expect them to be like that for some time to come.